# Can't change image source of element ID when using variable name instead of string

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function to change the src of an image based on two strings passed to the function, `a`, which is the element ID, and `b`, which is the new source for the image.

In this instance, I have confirmed that both variables are passed to the function correctly.

`console.log(a);` is *layerAddButton*

`console.log(b);` is *images/layerAdd-blue.svg*

Here is my code :

```
function swapImg(id,url)
{   
    var a = id;
    var b = url;
    
    document.getElementById(a).src = b;
}
```

This does not change the url of the image as expected, but gives an error in chrome :

> functions.js:3025 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null
> (setting 'src')
> at swapImg (functions.js:3025:32)
> at HTMLButtonElement.onmouseleave (app.htm:1132:274)

This works fine when I hard code like so :

`document.getElementById('layerAddButton').src = 'images/layerAdd-blue.svg';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it and it works. Make sure to write the Id correctly when passing it to the function. And make sure the script is in the HTML after the element and not in the head.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <img
    src="https://www.testingtime.com/app/uploads/2017/07/Grundregeln_fuer_User_Testing-750x500.jpg"
    alt=""
    id="imgElement"
  />
  <body>
    <script>
      function swapImg(id, url) {
        var a = id;
        var b = url;
        console.log(document.getElementById(a));
        document.getElementById(a).src = b;
      }

      swapImg("imgElement", "https://source.unsplash.com/random");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although I don't have it working still, this is the correct answer because it is indeed the order in which I wrote my code. This is correct.

Comment: Thanks, what is not working still? Can you share more code, then I can help you maybe.

Comment: Thank you, it is working now. I had too much going on in my code and it was indeed out of order. I just finished rewriting and it works great!

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, you just needed to pass the variable to the getElementById() function and not just the variable name.

The correct code should be :

```
function swapImg(id,url)
{   
    var a = id;
    var b = url;
    
    document.getElementById(a).src = b;
}
```